# How to restart Eclipse with bat

Tags: eclipse, batch-file

Most Eclipse applications have File -> Restart in their menus. Is it possible to restart application with some bat script in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Kill the eclipse process

   ```
   taskkill /im eclipse.exe
   ```
2. Wait a few seconds until the process is terminated

   ```
   sleep 10
   ```
3. Start the eclipse application

   ```
   start "C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe"
   ```

Comment: Often before restarting application Eclipse saves the current state, so killing the process is not the solution.

Comment: @akapelko, correct, killing the process should be not a solution. An alternative might be to use some windows automation tool, like AutoIT or AutoHK, to send the "close" commands to the eclipse window.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's generally not possible without bad side effects. The code to restart Eclipse is several hundred lines of Java code, carefully creating a new virtual machine process with all the right settings.